# How to check if Javascript is enabled in a browser

Tags: javascript, html

I want to know how to check if Javascript enabled in a browser. I need that to avoid server side validation.

Comment: Don't do that! Never avoid server side validation! Even if JS is enabled, everyone could make the GET or POST request either way. JS validation is only for user experience.

Comment: 12 questions, and NO accepted answers?   This is frowned on by the community.  You really should accept some answers if you're going to continue asking questions.

Answer (score 5):

You can perform various checks, like adding a hidden field to the form which you fill from Javascript. The server can check if this value if set, and if so, assume javascript is active.

But you should never rely on client side validation. Always perform server side validation. Client side validation is only an extra to improve usability.

Answer (score 4):

You don't want this.

Client-side validation is only something to notify your users of any wrongly-filled fields directly, but the real validation should be done server-side. The client could change the JavaScript and make it do what he wants, so it's not reliable.

Why don't you just always check server-side? It's more advantageous.

Answer (score 3):

You never want to avoid server side validation, just do it twice.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to detect if Javascript is enabled because your site requires it to be useful, or you have a different layout for non-Javascript users, you can use the `<noscript>` element. In it you can put whatever you want the user to see if they don't have Javascript enabled. This can be a simple message, or an entire page layout.

```html
<body>
    //normal layout here

    <noscript>
        //message or alternative layout here, Javascript users won't see this.
    </noscript>
</body>
```

If you want a totally new layout, you'll need to cover the other layout with something like this:

Demo (code): http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/nK4Ka/
Demo (page to view with no JS, since jsFiddle needs it): http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/nK4Ka/show/

HTML:

```html
<div>Hello, Javascript!</div>

<noscript>
    <div>Hello, No Javascript</div>
</noscript>
```

CSS:

```css
noscript {
    background-color: white;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    overflow: scroll;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```